# Automapper 7.0.1 ProjectTo mismatch types with ef core 2.1.1 linq join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper, automapper-7

Full exemple in Console application [gist](https://gist.github.com/antonio-campagnaro/c6554201420986958983cd370be725bc)

I have some entities with readonly property that is calculated.

This is my Automapper mapping config to calculate the property.

```
cfg.CreateMap(t, t).ForMember(nameof(ITestInterface.IsReadOnly), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ((ITestInterface)src).OrganizationUnitId == ((ITestInterface)src).TenantId));
```

And this is a simple query that throws exception

```
var simpleQuery = from super in context.SuperEntities.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<SuperEntity>()
                          join other in context.OtherSuperEntities.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<OtherSuperEntity>() on super.Id equals other.SuperEntityId
                          select new { super.IsReadOnly, other.OtherSuperDescription };
        var simpleResult = simpleQuery.ToList();
```

I got an InvalidOperationException:
An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'OtherSuperEntity.Id'. The expected type was 'System.Int64' but the actual value was of type 'System.Boolean'.

Is this an issue of automapper? They just closed my [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2919)

Comment: Try writing your query only using EF and then project just the result using AM.

Comment: Try moving `context.OtherSuperEntities.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<OtherSuperEntity>()` in variable outside the query expression tree.

Comment: I am using a generic repository pattern and i want to hide and automize the ProjectTo functions so i cant call it at the end of the linq query